# Getting sum in PHP MySQL

Tags: mysqli

I want to get sum of integers that are selected from mysql

Here is my code

```
<?php
Include 'init.php';
$page = '2459';

$ttl = array();

$search = $db->link->query("SELECT id,packid,rating FROM pakrate WHERE packid LIKE '%$q%'");

if($search->num_rows>0){
    while($result=$search->fetch_assoc()){
        $ttl[] = $row['rating'];

        echo $ttl;
        echo $result[SUM('rating')];
    }
}
else {
    echo "no such query";
}
```

So what I am doing wrong here, any other suggestions?

Comment: Put it in the query sum(rating) as sum FROM pakrate...

Comment: Can u explain? Because i didn't understand

Comment: Comments can be deleted, and so are not the best place for answers. @clearshot66 can you turn that comment into a candidate answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the sum in your query

```
<?php

Include 'init.php';
$page = '2459';

$ttl = array();

// Not sure why you're doing this but there should only be one leading connection ($conn->query) unless you're doing some object item elsewhere in init.

// I would also use prepared statements since they're more secure:

$q = "%$q%";   // create your like variable, wherever $q is coming from??

$query = "SELECT sum(rating) from pakrate WHERE packid LIKE ?);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);  // assuming $db is your connection variable
if($stmt){
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$q);  // Bind the variable in
   $stmt->execute();           // Execute
   $stmt->bind_result($rating);   // Bind the result variable
   $stmt->store_result();        // Store it so you can get num_rows
   $rows = $stmt->num_rows;    // assign rows found

   if($rows > 0){
       while($stmt->fetch()){    // Loop the result

       $ttl[] = $rating;   // add to your array

       // You can't echo an array like this.... echo $ttl;
       // if you really want to, print_r($ttl);
       }
   }
 $stmt->close(); // Close it
}

?>
```